# Is it bad idea to make an AJAX post call every 2 secs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

If I make an AJAX $.post call (with jQuery) to a php file for updating a certain parameter/number, does it considered bad practise, dangerous or similar?

```
$.post(file.php, {var:var}, function(data){
// something
}, json);
```

It would be a single user on a single page updating a number by clicking on an object. For example if user A is updating a certain number by clicking on an object user B should see this update immediately without reloading the page.

Comment: It depends, how many users do you have?

Comment: Users at the same time? Hmm, maybe 10. Not much…

Comment: it all goes down to your server configuration, how many concurrent connections does it support and how long does it take your request to process

Comment: Depends. Is it a single user making these calls, or lots of different users. If it's a single user, i recommend looking into websockets.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a single user on a single page updating a number by clicking on an object. For example if user A is updating a certain number by clicking on an object user B should see this update immediately without reloading the page.

Comment: Whoever rephrased my question to fix grammar or spelling mistakes: check again…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on 3 main factors:

1. How many users will you have at any given time?
2. How much data is being sent per request on average?
3. Given 1 and 2, is your sever set up to handle that kind of action?

I have a webapp that's set up to handle up to 10-20k users simultaneously, makes a request each time the user changes a value on their page (could be more than 1 req per second), and it sends roughly 1000 bytes on each request. I get an average of 10ms response time, however that's with node js. Originally I started the project in PHP but it turned out to be too slow for my needs.

I don't think web-sockets is the right tool for what you're doing, since you don't need the server to send to the client, and a constant connection can be much more expensive than sending a request every few seconds.

Just be sure to do lots of testing and then you can make judgements on whether it'll work out or not for your specific needs.

tl;dr - It's not a good idea if your server can't handle it. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
@1 Just about 10, probably
@2 Not much, just updating one digit/number. Max 1req/sec
Do you think it's worth working with web sockets here?

Comment: Oh, that's practically nothing. The ajax solution should work perfectly fine for what you're trying to accomplish. Web Sockets would be a waste of your time in this case. The only time where it really makes sense to use Web Sockets instead of ajax is when you need to send data from the server to the client as well as from the client to the server.

Comment: Thanks, I will just optimise it then!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be, to cache user actions in local storage/variables, and send them all at once every 10-15 seconds or so, then clear the cache, when sending was successful.

In this case you should also validate the data in local storage to prevent tampering.