# making ajax requests in every 2 seconds is doable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have to build a results viewing page where I have to list results of a voting process in live. I am planning to check for DB changes in every 2 seconds ? Is it doable ? will the page crash or get stuck after 1 or 2 hours?

Comment: if you ask me, from my experience, NO!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476817/is-it-bad-idea-to-make-an-ajax-post-call-every-2-secs#comment37884990_24476817

Comment: How many users are likely to be viewing the site?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/ this sample code makes a request a bit faster than that. I would be concerned about server load and bandwidth as the number of users increase.

Comment: This question is far too vague. It really depends on how many users are using this feature - which you have failed to share with us - what hardware you're using, and how much data is being sent back and forth with each AJAX request. With one million users, this feature is producing 30 million requests per minute! You have to ask yourself, is it worth it? Can you increase the interval to 8 or 10 seconds to help your server cope with the load? What is your server specification? Can it cope? Share more information please.

Comment: I will be using a shared server and 10-15 users, ajax response will a  few integer values in JSON format

Comment: It'll probably be okay as long as it's coded well, taking into account what happens if one request has latency etc, etc. I've seen chat applications pinging every 1 to 2 seconds like the one on CSS Tricks as @Wayne pointed out in the comments. I'd be inclined to set it to 5 or 10 seconds. You could also look into Websockets / Comet / APE Project for pushing real-time data saving all those requests.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use settimeout to call the ajax function.

The second better way would be  if its possible in your existing architectural setup, use setimeout for making an io connection and then checking for any event , this event is nothing else but a change in the db which is triggered by a node js server.

Comment: that has nothing to do with nodejs, what you're talking about is closer to a Model-View-Controller design pattern.